# What can I use instead of @?

Tags: c#, operator-keyword

I make an application for graduation project. Summary, I need to write the "bodyBefore" variable as similar to "body" variable. I couldn't translate it.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/server/login.php");

//request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0";
//request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
//request.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "tr-TR,tr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3");
//request.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip, deflate");
request.Referer = "http://localhost/server/index.html";
request.KeepAlive = true;
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

request.Method = "POST";
request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;

string bodyBefore = frm1.txtUserInput.Text+"="+frm1.txtUsername.Text+"&"+frm1.txtPassInput.Text+"="+frm1.txtPassword.Text+"&"+"submit=Login";
//string body = @bodyBefore;
string body = @"username=admin&password=12345&submit=Login";

MessageBox.Show("Body before : " + bodyBefore+"\nBody"+body);

byte[] postBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body);
request.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;
Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();
stream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
stream.Close();
```

There is no difference between body and bodyBefore strings:

[image]

Expectation of variables:

```
txtUsername : Textbox of username ///
txtPassword : Textbox of password ///
txtUserInput : Textbox of username input name in web page ///
txtPassInput : Textbox of password input name in web page
```

Comment: Could you explain more about the problem you're having?  Why are you trying to use '@'?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any reason to use the `@"` notation. Why do you think you need to?

Comment: @reuben - FYI - escaping is "back-tick", not "single-quote".

Comment: When I try to send informations using "body" variable, it works. But when I try to send informations using "bodyBefore", it couldn't send.

Comment: @AbdullahAlemdar The issue wouldn't be due to the `@` or lack of (it's an operator that only has meaning to the parser). The endpoint the request is sent to appears to expect both `username` and `password` fields. Currently, it would only receive those if you entered those words verbatim in the two input fields. The left side of each `=` in the string probably shouldn't be determined by the inputs.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Thanks. But how can I solve this problem? :(

Comment: @AbdullahAlemdar Sorry. I actually misread part of the snippet (missed that there were 4 controls). That said, what are the values of each control's `.Text`? What is the resulting value of `bodyBefore` and specifically how does it differ from `body` (as it appears in the `MessageBox`)? Do the `name=value` pairs match, including possibly in case (upper, lower, capitalized, etc.)?

Comment: @JonathanLonowski I want to see the differences between body and bodyBefore with using messagebox. There is not. I added other informations to post, friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved. When I edit "body" variable as below, it works.

```
string body = string.Format("{0}={1}&{2}={3}&submit=Login", frm1.txtUserInput.Text, frm1.txtUsername.Text, frm1.txtPassInput.Text, frm1.txtPassword.Text);
```

Thanks for helps.